# Include a lambda inside an if..else statement

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function:

```kotlin
fun ValueListItem(
    label: String,
    value: String,
    onClick: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {

}
```

But calling it like this is not allowed:

```kotlin
var edited = false

ValueListItem(
    label = "my label",
    value = "some value",
    onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) { edited = true } else null
)
```

But calling it like this is allowed:

```kotlin
var edited = false

val onEditDateTime = {
  edited = true
}

ValueListItem(
    label = "my label",
    value = "some value",
    onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) onEditDateTime else null
)
```

How can I pass the lambda in a conditional statement rather than having to declare the lambda as an extra construct.

Comment: Try `onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) {{ edited = true }} else null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By writing

```
ValueListItem(
    label = "my label",
    value = "some value",
    onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) { edited = true } else null
)
```

The compiler sees the braces as part of the if-statement syntax.
Simply adding another pair of braces like this should do the trick I think

```
ValueListItem(
    label = "my label",
    value = "some value",
    onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) {{ edited = true }} else null
)
```

Comment: `(` instead of `{` also works,  `onClick = if (viewmodel.canEdit) ({ edited = true }) else null`